# How to Restrict access to particular page to only 1 logged in user?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am making a simple Social Media Website using Java Spring Boot. Now I want to add a profile edit page, where a logged in user can edit/update his profile data but other logged in users should not have access to it.

For example, there are two people John and Tom, John should be able to see only his profile edit page and Tom should see only his Profile edit page Only after login.

How to achieve this using Spring Security or by any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to write `BeanAccessor` like following:

```
@Component
public class BeanAccessor implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        return getBean(ObjectMapper.class);
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass, Object... args) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass, args);
    }

    private static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

then we need to write new class for method security like:

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    private Object filterObject;

    private Object returnObject;

    private Object target;

    public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
    }

    CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot setTarget(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterObject(Object filterObject) {
        this.filterObject = filterObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFilterObject() {
        return filterObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject) {
        this.returnObject = returnObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getReturnObject() {
        return returnObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getThis() {
        return target;
    }

}
```

finally we need custom method security expressinon handler:

```
@Component
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator;

    private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
        final CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = BeanAccessor.getBean(CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot.class, authentication);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(customPermissionEvaluator);
        root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        root.setTarget(invocation.getThis());
        return root;
    }

}
```

now on your controller method yo can define `@PreAuthorize("isProfileOwner(#id)")` annotations your user profile show page method looks like :

```
@PreAuthorize("isProfileOwner(#id)")
@GetMapping("{id}")
public String show(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
//omitted
}
```

everything okey but we need to write `isProfileOwner()` method to our `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot` class like:

```
public boolean isProfileOwner(Long id) {
//add logic here and you are ready
}
```

also you can check this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I will surely try this out. But I don’t understand a single line of code written above. Lol. I am Beginner at this kind of stuff so Can You please tell me from where can I learn this.

Comment: I've attached a blog post you can read out, and you can read spring security doc, I am assuming the you knew other spring boot related things. Also, you can follow baeldung blog posts. He is writing really useful blogs.